# Changing json to java pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper, objectmapper

Let's say I have a JSON file example.json

```
example.json

    {
      "BaggageMaxSize" : {
            "mesurement" : "sum",
            "width" : 70,
            "height" : 50,
            "depth" : 40
        }
    }
```

And create the POJO class:

```
    public class pojoexample{
      private BaggageMaxSize BaggageMaxSize;
      // getter
      // setter
    }
```

And then:

```
public class BaggageMaxSize
{
    private String height;

    private String width;

    private String depth;

    private String mesurement;

    // getter 
    // setter
}
```

Now, I want to use the mapper.readValue to change file to BaggageInfoPolicy.class:

```
BaggageInfoPolicy bip = mapper.readValue(file, BaggageInfoPolicy.class);
```

But `bip.getBaggageMaxSize().getMesurement()` returns null value. Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure what its not working overall, but note that you have integer values in the json for width/height/depth but String types on the bean. also check your spelling as mesurement should be measurement

Comment: What are you using for mapping?

Comment: it looks like Jackson

Comment: What's `BaggageInfoPolicy`?!! It should be `pojoexample`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mapper.writeValue` first and check how your resulting JSON object will look like. Very likely, there's an issue with `int -> string` conversion in your `BaggageMaxSize` when deserialized from JSON.

Also, check your getters/setters to be publicly visible and be available both on `pojoexample` and `BaggageMaxSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your JSON represents a `pojoexample` class instance and not a `BaggageInfoPolicy` object, which you haven't shared in your post.

So you need to change your code to:

```
PojoExample bip = mapper.readValue(file, PojoExample.class);
```

So it reads the `PojoExample` object correctly.

**Note:**

- Your `class` should follow the java naming convention and
  start with an uppercase, that's why I changed it to `PojoExample`,
  change it in the class definition as well.
- And Make sure your class fields have the same `types` as in the JSON, and their `getters` and `setters` are correctly implemented.